# Sendgrid - scheduled emails cancellation

Tags: sendgrid, cancellation

We are letting users create webinars. Each webinar can have 1-10000 attendees for example. So if user scheduled webinar reminder emails and then plans to cancel those 1-10000. Is this possible to cancel such bulk number of emails with sendgrid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [cancel scheduled sends](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/cancel_schedule_send.html) via SendGrid. You can only have up to 10 batches and you can only schedule up to 72 hours in advance.